# Struggling formating xticks with DateTime from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm currently struggling with my xaxis format.. the date doesnt start at 2017 but somewhere in the year 1138.
Is there something I've done wrong?
my tick labeling should be like Thu 01.06.2017, Fri 02.06.2017, etc.

```
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU

Gesamt_Apr_Sept_2017 = pd.read_csv('Gesamtstromverbrauch_Met_01.04.2017-30.09.2017-1h.csv',sep=';',decimal = ",", thousands = '.', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
Daten = Gesamt_Apr_Sept_2017['6/1/2017':'06/30/2017']

# Figure erzeugen
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

Daten['LKHF-Strom-Met - Gesamt (kWh)'].plot()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator(interval=7))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%a %d.%m.%Y'))

for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)
```

diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J9Mf.jpg

The Dataframe looks like:

```
Date    
2017-04-01 01:00:00 1008.0
2017-04-01 02:00:00 996.0
2017-04-01 03:00:00 976.0
2017-04-01 04:00:00 984.0
2017-04-01 05:00:00 1024.0

dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date', length=720, freq=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `Daten['LKHF-Strom-Met - Gesamt (kWh)'].plot()` with `Daten[['LKHF-Strom-Met - Gesamt (kWh)']].plot()` to fix your error.
Short explanation why: 
df[col] returns a Pandas Series and df[[col]] a Pandas Dataframe and for the Dataframe the plot function uses the index as x-axis.

```
%pylab inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from matplotlib.dates import MO, TU, WE, TH, FR, SA, SU

Gesamt_Apr_Sept_2017 = pd.read_csv('Gesamtstromverbrauch_Met_01.04.2017-30.09.2017-1h.csv',sep=';',decimal = ",", thousands = '.', index_col=0, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)
Daten = Gesamt_Apr_Sept_2017['6/1/2017':'06/30/2017']

# Figure erzeugen
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,6))

Daten[['LKHF-Strom-Met - Gesamt (kWh)']].plot()

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(DayLocator(interval=7))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(DateFormatter('%a %d.%m.%Y'))

for tick in ax.get_xticklabels():
    tick.set_rotation(90)
```